# Why doesn't crontab run if screensaver is on?

Tags: screensaver, cron

I want to run a Crontab on OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan).

I'm running the command:

```
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

to enter the crontab with nano as the editor.

Then I create my cronjob that looks like this:

```
50 */15 * * * touch /home/test.txt
```

If I go to `/home/` there is nothing:

```
User 15:50:home $ ls -la
total 2
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 25 Nov 14:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  31 root  wheel  1122 29 Okt 10:02 ..
```

Why doesn't the cronjob run if the screensavers is on and screen is locked?

Comment: Do you have permission to  touch in /home (which is a non standard (OS X  place) do ls -la in the directory above Is */15 the correct syntax. Is touch on the path (and which path cron uses a different one). The normal way for OS X is use launchd - and use a tool like Launch Control

Comment: Sry i don't get your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/home` is used by the automounter and can't be written to. Just try with another directory (eg `/tmp`).